# Apache Spark error while trying to execute PySpark script

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've been trying to create a simple dataframe and for starters, write it down to a csv file but I'm getting the following error:

```
 Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/01/03 10:06:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\VirtualEnv\test_env\pyspark.py", line 21, in <module>
    df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv(csv_path, header=True)
  File "C:\spark3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1864, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "C:\spark3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\spark3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o44.csv.
: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:1007)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:900)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:1288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:978)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:788)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:356)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:240)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:850)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

SUCCESS: The process with PID 24816 (child process of PID 10636) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 10636 (child process of PID 21164) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 21164 (child process of PID 11016) has been terminated.
```

This is just a chunk of the error, the whole stacktrace is fairly big. I tried playing around with different Spark (and Hadoop) versions, Python versions, winutil versions, etc.

Thank you in advance,
Bojan

playing around with different Spark (and Hadoop) versions, Python versions, winutil versions, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Plz provide the full log error.

Comment: Thank you Rm4n, I've updated the error log in the original post

Comment: i cannot find the original code you are trying to execute, that results into this error. its hard to make guesses unless we know what got you this error

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this by playing around with older versions of Python and Spark. Marking this as resolved. Thank you all